# Insert into columns ending with _ID

Tags: sql, insert

I have a table with 219 columns.
I need to insert '-99' into the columns where column name is ending with '_ID' (eg: PARTY_ID, NAME_ID) and 5 of the columns I want to load from a table 'xyz' and rest I want to mark as null.

Please help

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? Oracle/MS SQL/MySQL/MySQL/etc...

Comment: and what did you achieve yourself already? i mean your code/SQL

Comment: This is not possible. You will have to explicitely specify all column names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, one can generate insert statement fetching data from information_schema/"internal dictionary" and execute this statement... But the topic-starter didn't specify the DB she/he is working with, so, yes, now it is not possible to give a general answer which would work on any RDBMS. :)

Comment: @MaxU: the generated statement will still explicitly specify all columns - it's just less typing.

Comment: I am working in netezza